gradle project load is not loading the dependencies to Maven(.m2) repository
I have loaded a new gradle spring boot project to Intellij and when the project is imported, all the dependencies are getting downloaded to gradle cache but not to the mavenLocal(~/.m2/repository). I have all the below but nothing worked. My gradle version is 8.8
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

export MAVEN_REPO=/Users/user_name/.m2/repository
export M2_HOME=/Users/user_name/.m2/repository
gradle clean build --no-build-cache
gradle --refresh-dependencies
have the below plugins in my build.gradle :
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'idea'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

